# Is there any way to see and log the jniThrowRuntimeException and ALOGE function to my .log file? In Android source code

Tags: android, logging, frameworks, android-source

Is there a way to log the jniThrowRuntimeException and ALOGE function to my .log file? In Android source code.
My Andoird version is Android8.0, download the source code from google git.
I have roughly confirmed that the code will enter the function where I want to print the log.

jniThrowRuntimeException is in Android core in com_android_server_input_InputManagerService.cpp, ALOGE is in Android native in InputDispatcher.cpp. Here are the code image.
My question is where can I find the output, or can I redirecet to a log.
I try `adb loagcat >report.log` or `adb shell dmesg` or `adb logcat -b system`, but it failed that I cannot find any log related to the functions.

[jniThrowRuntimeException function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkpS3.png)
[ALOGE function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZAfA.png)

I searched infos from web and chatgpt and trid to sovle.
I trid `adb loagcat >report.log` or `adb shell dmesg` or `adb logcat -b system`, but it failed that I cannot find any log related to the functions.